# How do I find and stop an imported module that is replicating my log only in my console?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

This is my my logger setup.

```
def get_log():

    # Create a custom base_logger
    base_logger = logging.getLogger()
    base_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    
    # Create handlers
    file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
        'logs/runtime.log', when='midnight', interval=1, backupCount=7, encoding='utf-8'
    )
    file_handler.namer = my_namer
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    # Create formatters and add it to handlers
    main_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    # The console sends only messages by default no need for formatter
    file_handler.setFormatter(main_format)
    
    # Add handlers to the base_logger
    base_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    base_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

I initialize it like this in other modules.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This part is only in the main module.

```
get_log()
logger.debug("Logging Started")
................

logger.debug("Logging Ended\n")
```

This is what my console looks like (my console is only meant to show messages).

```
[2022-12-04 10:59:43,533] [   DEBUG] main.py:110 - Logging Started
[2022-12-04 10:59:43,556] [    INFO] main.py:91 - File Path: tests\I Can Copy Talents.mp4
[2022-12-04 10:59:43,556] [    INFO] main.py:92 - Frame Rate: 30, Frame Count: 522
[2022-12-04 10:59:43,556] [    INFO] main.py:93 - Resolution: 1920 X 1080
[2022-12-04 10:59:43,556] [    INFO] main.py:94 - Subtitle Area: (0, 810, 1920, 1080)
[2022-12-04 10:59:43,556] [    INFO] main.py:96 - Start to extracting video keyframes...
File Path: tests\I Can Copy Talents.mp4
Frame Rate: 30, Frame Count: 522
Resolution: 1920 X 1080
Subtitle Area: (0, 810, 1920, 1080)
Start to extracting video keyframes...
[2022-12-04 10:59:43,573] [   DEBUG] video_frames_ocr.py:131 - frame chunks = [[0, 250], [250, 500],[500, 521]]
[2022-12-04 10:59:43,573] [   DEBUG] video_frames_ocr.py:133 - Using multiprocessing for frames
Extracting frames from video:  |##################################################| 100.000% Complete
[2022-12-04 11:00:01,701] [    INFO] main.py:102 - Subtitle file generated successfully, Total time: 18.145s
[2022-12-04 11:00:01,708] [   DEBUG] main.py:119 - Logging Ended

Subtitle file generated successfully, Total time: 18.145s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is what my file log looks like. It doesn't contain the replication

```
2022-12-04 10:59:43,533 - __main__ - DEBUG - Logging Started
2022-12-04 10:59:43,556 - __main__ - INFO - File Path: tests\I Can Copy Talents.mp4
2022-12-04 10:59:43,556 - __main__ - INFO - Frame Rate: 30, Frame Count: 522
2022-12-04 10:59:43,556 - __main__ - INFO - Resolution: 1920 X 1080
2022-12-04 10:59:43,556 - __main__ - INFO - Subtitle Area: (0, 810, 1920, 1080)
2022-12-04 10:59:43,556 - __main__ - INFO - Start to extracting video keyframes...
2022-12-04 10:59:43,573 - video_frames_ocr - DEBUG - frame chunks = [[0, 250], [250, 500], [500, 521]]
2022-12-04 10:59:43,573 - video_frames_ocr - DEBUG - Using multiprocessing for frames
2022-12-04 11:00:01,701 - __main__ - INFO - Subtitle file generated successfully, Total time: 18.145s
2022-12-04 11:00:01,708 - __main__ - DEBUG - Logging Ended
```

I have tried using setting propagate to false but it just stops my logs in that module from showing.

I have no idea which module is doing this because it only printing my logs and not its.

Comment: In `logger.debug("Logging Started")` where did `logger` come from? `get_log` is really `configure_log` and should be run once before anybody does any logging (and never again). Otherwise, you run the risk that a prior logging call does a basic config and that log handler is also on the root logger.

Comment: @tdelaney , the `get_log` is in a different module that i use as a logger setup/config, it gets called in the main module under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` so it should run just once

Comment: In `__main__`, do the `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` after calling `get_log`. This looks like something else has already configured the logger before you go to it. Just speculating on why. You could do `print(logger.handlers)` to see if it has more than the 2 you created.

Comment: @tdelaney, thanks for trying to help but, it doesn't work. I put the logger on the first line but i'm still getting the problem. I thought it worked but that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm out of guesses.